# Vba changing .Vlookup to .vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to `vlookup` some data from one sheet to the other.
Whenever I try `Vlookup` using VBA: the result is `Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup`
instead of
`Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

This is happening only in this project. Even if I try creating a new module, it doesn't help.
I tried in a new project and it works perfectly fine there.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(2, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction _
    .vlookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(2, 1), _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Constraints Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 2)), 3, False)
```

EDIT: this snippet worked as the column was out of range. However, the error persists in the following snippet

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DAH DATA")
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Constraints Data")

lastrow2 = wb.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
lastcol2 = wb.Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
wb.Activate
Set rng1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow2, lastcol2))

sh.Cells(132, 22).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup _
("7/30/2019", rng1, 2, 0)
```

As a result of this I get

> Error 1004: Unable to get VLookup property of Worksheet function
>   class.

Comment: That won't affect how it works (the error is because your lookup value isn't found); it just means you have (or had) used the word `vlookup` as the name of something in your code.

Comment: Are you sure there should be a match? The error is thrown when Vlookup is unable to find one.

Comment: Thankyou,my apologies for the typo in the code. This snippet worked but the error still exists in the other snippet which I am adding the question itself.

Comment: You should specify in which worksheet these `Range` and `Cells` objects are `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow2, lastcol2))`!

Answer (score 2):

The way it behaves indicates that you have declared a variable with name of `vlookup` and now it tries to correct whenever you type `VLookup`.

I suggest you use `Option Explicit` (just type it at the top of your code file).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the 3rd column of the range BUT your range has only 2 columns.

You have to options:

1. If the range you look has 2 columns - Change `3, False)` to `2, False)`
2. If the range you look has 3 columns - Change `wsB.Cells(3, 2))` to `wsB.Cells(3, 3))`

I try to simplify the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet


    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsA = .Sheets("Sheet5")
        Set wsB = .Sheets("Constraints Data")
    End With

    wsA.Cells(2, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wsA.Cells(2, 1), wsB.Range(wsB.Cells(1, 1), wsB.Cells(3, 2)), 3, False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are searching in range `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Constraints Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, 2))`

That range is 3 rows 2 columns.

But in your VLOOKUP, in third argument, you type `3` to retrieve the value in the third column.

And there is not third column. That causes the error.